# VBA / excel macro - find part of string in list of values and then return that value

Tags: excel, vba

First post here, so apologies if I break any etiquette. If something is missing please let me know so I can edit my post if needed.

I'm currently working on an Excel macro, which enables me to import an interactive pdf form into excel and read data that was written in the form. Most of the script I have down by finding bits and pieces all over the internet, just one specific problem I wasn't able to solve so far.

I have one text field in my pdf that I need to split in two and save the new values in two separate cells. Not a big problem so far, but the formatting may differ, depending on the entered data, so just cutting it of after e.g. a certain amount of characters won't work. Also the quality of the user input data may not be always the same (e.g. sometimes using a hyphen between both parts of the string, using an underscore or no seperator at all). Unfortunately I can't give that text field in the pdf form a strict formatting rule, as the formatting may differ. I also cannot just make to separate form fields in the pdf file for each part of the string. The ease of use is supposed to be on the pdf user's side, not on mine...

Now, what does the data look like:
ABC-1234
ABCD-0123
A1B-12A

As you can see there is not a clear pattern. Please note that as said before the hyphen may not be there or be replaced by an underscore. I added it here to show you the separation of the two sub datasets (lets call them "Data A" for everything on the left side and "Data B" for everything on the right side of the hyphen).

The good thing! I know all the potential values Data A may have. Data B is then just supposed to be stored separately in another cell. My first train of thought was to use InStr, but that may not be the most elegant solution. Data A may be one of around 130 different values, which is also frequently growing. My excel file also has a "helper sheet", in which I store some information for e.g. dropdown menus or deadlines etc. I could store a list of potential Data A candidates here as well.

So what exactly do I need? A method to look at the string, compare it to a list of substrings (Data A, e.g. using a column in my excel sheet as data source) and store that match in Cell A1. Then take that value away from the original string so only Data B remains (I can strip away any hyphens or underscores at this point) and store this value in Cell A2.

**Examples:**
My import data may look like this: BER1234
Compare this to my list of match candidates, which includes "BER".
Cell A1 = "BER"
Cell A2 = (string minus the match) 1234

Import data: BERA59
Match in my candidate list: BERA
A1 = "BERA"
A2 = "59"

Import data: P9CD-1009A
Match: P9CD
A1 = "P9CD"
A2 = "1009A"

etc.

I may be able to do this with a giant block of if/else and many many InStr comparisons. Problem is, whenever I need to add a new match candidate I will have to go back to coding. It would make my life way easier if I could just e.g. add the value at the bottom of my candidate list and let the macro do it's magic.

I would love to post a piece of code here of what I did so far, unfortunately I really have no idea where to start. I do not expect a ready-to-use piece of code that I can just slab in my macro with copy and paste. If I can't understand the code, I usually go for another solution. Otherwise I can't fix it myself if anything breaks and I don't really like that approach. Giving me pointers on which functions and variable types to look at would be greatly appreciated, though. Maybe I can then piece together what I think it should look like and ask for more help after that step.

My experience level: Kind of beginner, but not total beginner. I have a basic understanding of how things work, but I'm not "fluent" in any programming languages. I know what I want to do and then usually try to get it to work by piecing together different solutions I find on the internet. So far so good, this one's a bit illusive for me, though. Any help is greatly appreciated. As mentioned before, if anything is missing or unclear, I'll gladly try to update this post.

With the suggestions I somewhat got it to work with this:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Remover As String
    Dim CatNo As String
    Dim Matches As Integer
            
    With Sheets("MenuData")
        LastRow = .Range("o" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    LastRow = LastRow - 4
    Matches = 0
            
    For x = 1 To LastRow
        If InStr(AlbumCode1, wb.Sheets("MenuData").Range("O" & x + 4).Value) <> 0 Then
            Matches = Matches + 1
            Range(ColCatalog & (ImportCell.Row)).Value = wb.Sheets("MenuData").Range("O" & x + 4).Value
            Remover = wb.Sheets("MenuData").Range("O" & x + 4).Value
            CatNo = Replace(AlbumCode1, Remover, "")
            Range(ColCatNo & (ImportCell.Row)).Value = CatNo
        End If
                
    Next
    
    MsgBox Matches & (" Matches")
```

What I do is count the rows and substract 4, because my candidate list starts on row 4. Then do the loop for each x. I have declared all the Colxxx variables as Const at the very beginning of the macro. ImportCell is also declared somewhere else and working as intended for the rest of the data I import. My "Remover" is just set to the value of the match and then gets used to strip it away from the original string that is stored in AlbumCode1 (declared also at the beginning of the macro). Probably not strictly neccessary to do it this way.

So far it works. My candidates may look like this, though:
BER
BERA

If I import data like "BERA12342" I will get two matches (the MsgBox here is for checking what my code does and will be deleted later). As the candidate BERA comes after the candidate BER in my source list it's working fine, because the 2nd "match" just overwrites the first. If they were to be in a different order I would get a false match. Is there a way to only always get one match? Or will I have to make sure the source list is ordered in a certain way?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the candidate list in an Excel file.
If so, you can use a for each loop on the range of your candidate list

To get the full candidate list, even if it grows between two executions, you can use the first cell as a starting point and find the last cell with the toDown() method.

I don't remember its exact name but I've used it before, you can find it by recording a macro and using the `Ctrl+Down` shortcut.

With these two cells you have the range of your candidate list.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a piece of code based on your suggestion and it kind of works. There is one more problem I would like to get rid of, though. See my original post for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that formula to check if the cell contains the string:

=IF(IFERROR(FIND("string",A2,1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("string",A2,1),0)>0,"TRUE","FALSE")
source: https://best-excel-tutorial.com/59-tips-and-tricks/600-search-for-string-in-column

Then filter them out and write a for loop to move forward.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to do this in vba, though. Is there a way to use this syntax in macros as well? Will this piece of code also find partial matches or only exact ones?